# HDMI monitor is not recognized

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hdmi, hybrid-graphics

I've got new laptop Lenovo Ideapad l340. I've installed ubuntu 19.04 and I can't connect external HDMI monitor. Could somebody help me to determine whether it's issue of the laptop or it's issue of ubuntu?

My xrandr

```
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```

lspci

```
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a369 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a328 (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f91 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5005 (rev 01)
07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

lsmod

```
rfcomm                 77824  4
ccm                    20480  6
cmac                   16384  1
bnep                   24576  2
snd_hda_codec_realtek   114688  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
nvidia_uvm            831488  0
arc4                   16384  2
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  2
intel_rapl             24576  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
nvidia_drm             45056  5
nvidia_modeset       1085440  1 nvidia_drm
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_soc_skl           106496  0
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       28672  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_skl_ipc        65536  1 snd_soc_skl
kvm_intel             241664  0
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_dsp        36864  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    28672  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          233472  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
nvidia              17604608  260 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
snd_hda_intel          40960  4
snd_hda_codec         131072  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           86016  8 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
i915                 1814528  3
snd_pcm               102400  8 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
kvmgt                  28672  0
vfio_mdev              16384  0
mdev                   24576  2 kvmgt,vfio_mdev
vfio_iommu_type1       28672  0
ath10k_pci             40960  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
vfio                   32768  3 kvmgt,vfio_mdev,vfio_iommu_type1
ath10k_core           434176  1 ath10k_pci
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
kvm                   626688  2 kvmgt,kvm_intel
btusb                  49152  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
ath                    36864  1 ath10k_core
btrtl                  20480  1 btusb
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
mac80211              806912  1 ath10k_core
btintel                24576  1 btusb
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
drm_kms_helper        180224  2 nvidia_drm,i915
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
bluetooth             557056  31 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
aesni_intel           372736  6
drm                   475136  8 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
uvcvideo               98304  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mei_me                 40960  0
joydev                 24576  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
idma64                 20480  0
cfg80211              671744  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
serio_raw              20480  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
8250_dw                20480  0
ecdh_generic           28672  2 bluetooth
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
virt_dma               20480  1 idma64
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
ideapad_laptop         36864  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
int3403_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
int3400_thermal        20480  0
acpi_tad               16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
acpi_pad              184320  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
xfs                  1232896  2
libcrc32c              16384  1 xfs
hid_rmi                24576  0
rmi_core               77824  1 hid_rmi
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  2 rmi_core,uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  2 rmi_core,uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       49152  3 rmi_core,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              200704  4 rmi_core,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
media                  53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
hid_generic            16384  0
nvme                   40960  3
r8169                  81920  0
ahci                   40960  0
realtek                20480  0
i2c_i801               32768  0
nvme_core              94208  5 nvme
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_hid                28672  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
hid                   126976  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,hid_rmi
wmi                    28672  3 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop
pinctrl_cannonlake     36864  0
video                  45056  2 ideapad_laptop,i915
pinctrl_intel          28672  1 pinctrl_cannonlake
```

EDIT:
The second monitor works until I set `options nvidia-drm modeset=1` in nvidia-drm kernel module options. But I get screen tearing until the option is 0

Comment: Which graphics are you using when it doesn't work? Or it doesn't work with both?

Comment: With both. I've got new details. It doesn't work if I set `options nvidia-drm modeset=1`. But If set this option to 0 I get tearing

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo Ideapad L340 has a muxed graphics configuration, which means, that laptop screen output (your `eDP-1-1` from `xrandr`) is wired to the integrated Intel card and the HDMI output is wired to the NVIDIA card. Everything defaultly runs over Intel. If you run `xrandr --listproviders`, you'll probably get only one provider (Intel, not NVIDIA). So you don't see the HDMI port, because xrandr simply does not see the NVIDIA display provider (although the nvidia module is loaded).

To answer your question `is it issue of the laptop or OS`: both, your laptop is designed in the way that it is not easy to get to HDMI port. Also, L340 has no GPU switch in BIOS, which would be fastest solution. On the other hand, linux does not provide simple way to work around this either.

Possible solutions:

- if you use bumblebee, check out this multimonitor setup (part with `intel-video-output` might be useful. It should create a virtual display that is sent to NVIDIA): https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup
- if you don't mind using NVIDIA only, you can use PRIME / GPU offloading / Reverse Prime (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME#Reverse_PRIME). It basicaly bypasses Intel card (depending on which method you choose)
- since there is no BIOS option to disable Intel card, you can try to use `vga_switcheroo`, which can disable Intel card on the fly and use NVIDIA on everything, though I'm not sure if your model supports it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Tell me if you succeed with any methods or find solution elsewhere.

EDIT: **option 2 works for me**. I have the same laptop, use NVIDIA proprietary drivers and set up `xorg.conf` file like described [here](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/375.26/README/randr14.html) . To make it work, I had to replace `Screen 0` with `Screen 1` on the 3rd line of `xorg.conf` example file.

Comment: But everything works fine until I set `options nvidia-drm modeset=1`. Also, my `xrandr --listproviders` shows `Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x239 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x43 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting`

Comment: Does `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` exist? Or anything in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`? If so, please paste it as edit note to your question as well as what happens when you set modeset to 0 and 1, so that new readers know the current status right after reading your question and don't have to read all the comments.

Comment: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` doesn't exist as well as `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`